# How do I sort posts with multiple pages

Tags: wp-query, sort, order, dropdown, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I am using a drop-down to sort posts by title, meta_value, etc. However, the sorting feature only works on the first page. The second page displays the default order rather than continuing the order from page 1. I am using wp-pagenavi for pagination. Any ideas what would be causing this error?

Here's a link to the code:

http://pastebin.com/AwSmMPtM

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You're initially submitting a `POST` request via a form with the sort parameters. When you click links to additional pages, you're just sending a `GET` request for the next page without those original `POST` vars, so they don't carry over to the additional pages and aren't picked up by your `if(isset($_REQUEST['sort']))`. Probably the simpler way to handle it is to pass the sort parameter as a query string appended to the URL, then check for that query string and append it to the URLs of the additional pages.

Comment: Upvoted... didn't notice the form action.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I understand what you're saying. Unfortunately, I don't know enough PHP to know what this looks like in code. Would you be able to provide a coding example of what you're suggesting? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `$paged` ***after*** the `if` conditionals that use it.

```
// more uses of $paged that way ^^^^
else
        $order = array(
        'cat' => 30,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged
);

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Put that `$paged =` line before those conditionals and I bet it makes a difference.